# How to add header to getServerSideProps in Next.js

Tags: next.js, http-headers

I want to pass JWT access token with a getServersideProps in Next.js. The token is stored in local storage.
Is there any way to do it?

Want to add headers to getServerSideProps in Next.js

Comment: You can't access `localStorage` in `getServerSideProps` as it runs on the server. Try passing the token through cookies instead.

Comment: Why do you have multiple SO accounts?

Answer (score 4):

`getServerSideProps` accepts a [`context`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) parameter which includes keys for accessing the `IncomingMessage` ([`req`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage)) and `ServerResponse` ([`res`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse)) objects. If you want to add a header, you can use the response object's `setHeader` method.

```js
export function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // print incoming headers
  console.log(context.req.headers);

  // add header
  context.res.setHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```